# Why is the zfs-dracut package kept back?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, zfs

I have recently upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04, which also upgraded my zfs versions ... except for this one package, `zfs-dracut`. It "has been kept back".

As can be seen in the output of `apt policy zfs-dracut`, the problem is *not* that it's a phased upgrade.

```bash
generic@motorbrot:/media/generic$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  alsa-ucm-conf firmware-sof-signed ubuntu-advantage-tools zfs-dracut
# [more irrelevant stuff here]

generic@motorbrot:~$ sudo apt policy zfs-dracut
zfs-dracut:
  Installed: 0.8.4-1
  Candidate: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
     2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     2.1.2-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 0.8.4-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

My zfs version is currently:

```
generic@motorbrot:~$ zfs --version
zfs-2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1
zfs-kmod-2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1
```

While there are many questions on askubuntu asking about why "packages have been kept back", the answers tend to suggest the following:

- it's a phased update. just wait.
  That would show up in the `apt policy` output though.
- just install it ( `apt install --upgrade-only zfs-dracut`, `apt install zfs-dracut`, `apt full-upgrade`, `apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade`, ... )
  None of these made a difference.
- The package was *marked* as held back.
  It is in my case not, `sudo apt-mark showhold zfs-dracut` has no output.
- just purge and reinstall it.
  I could do that, but I am worried it might have been held back for a good reason and purging it would break something. Especially since I am running zfs on root.

**Why** was this package held back?
(and **How** could I figure that out myself? )

---

To follow-up on the comments: Here is what happens when I do some of the things I have mentioned to not work. These excerpts are more current, so contain other packages too. Those others are `phased` as per `apt policy`.

```bash
generic@motorbrot:/media/generic$ sudo apt list --upgradeable
[sudo] password for generic: 
Listing... Done
alsa-ucm-conf/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.4 all [upgradable from: 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.3]
libnvpair3linux/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1]
libuutil3linux/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1]
libzfs4linux/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1]
libzpool5linux/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1]
python3-pyzfs/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 27.13.5~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 27.13.3~22.04.1]
zfs-dkms/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 all [upgradable from: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1]
zfs-dracut/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.8.4-1]
zfs-initramfs/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1]
zfs-test/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1]
zfs-zed/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1]
zfsutils-linux/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.1.4-0ubuntu0.1]

generic@motorbrot:/media/generic$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  alsa-ucm-conf libnvpair3linux libuutil3linux libzfs4linux libzpool5linux python3-pyzfs
  ubuntu-advantage-tools zfs-dkms zfs-dracut zfs-initramfs zfs-test zfs-zed zfsutils-linux
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
```

**Warning**: an answer suggests to run `apt install zfs-dracut dracut zfsutils-linux`. That, in my case, uninstalled `zfs-initramfs`, issued a warning, then failed installing `zfs-dracut`, and because I am more curious than is healthy I rebooted and now was stuck with an initramfs that does not know zfs. I fixed this up from a live stick but this is not a great outcome anyway.
For anyone in the same situation: I essentially followed [this guide](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/chroot-to-repair-system): Boot from a live-usb stick, import but don't mount your zfs pool, mount a snapshot back from when booting still worked with `zfs mount -t zfs tank/your_dataset@something /mnt/rescue`, bind-mount all that is needed (especially boot and efi partitions), chroot into it and run `update-initramfs -u -k all` (or at least the latest kernel version that shows up in `ls -la /lib/modules`).

These proposed fixes are potentially useful (or harmful), but essentially miss to answer my question: **Why** was zfs-dracut kept back?

**Sidenote** for people with this exact same problem: The actual **fix** was to completely uninstall `zfs-dracut` and re-install `zfs-initramfs`, then running `update-initramfs -u -k all` again.
This is irrelevant to the question though.

Comment: `zfs-dracut/jammy-updates 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.8.4-1]`. You don't have an *old* package, you have an *ancient* package, This is not obscure-but-normal. It's unusual, and requires troubleshooting.

Comment: Well, afaict it was the latest available package on ubuntu 18.04. The other zfs packages had similar versions but have upgraded themselves during the upgrade.

Comment: How, exactly, did you "upgrade from 18.04 to 22.04"?  Did you upgrade to 20.04 first, then to 22.04?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I ran essentially `apt update && apt upgrade && apt autoremove && do-release-upgrade -m "desktop"` once on ubuntu 18.04, which brought me to 20.04, and then once more to get from 20.04 to 22.04. If you think more information is useful (e.g. that i uninstalled ROS, that I chose to use the new `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` file instead of my old lightly patched one, etc) I could edit the question. I took lots of notes - but not sure which part would be relevant.

Comment: did you run into zfs-dracut problems at the 20.04 step or the 22.04 step? I'm thinking it didn't successfully upgrade to 20.04. wait - looks like you have the 20.04 version installed - although not exactly. Weird, and implies some kind of manual tinkering was done. Latest in 20.04 is 0.8.3-1ubuntu12.14 and yours is newer than that, but older than the 22.04 version.

Comment: @OrganicMarble hm, could be indeed. I have never before encountered `zfs-dracut` or `dracut` back when I initially set up zfs on root, as far as I can remember. How can you tell it is from 20.04? Sidenote: due to messing up my initramfs after asking this question, I have completely uninstalled zfs-dracut and reinstalled zfs-initramfs and it seems to be working again. I could go to an older snapshot for investigation though

Comment: @OrganicMarble regarding "manual tinkering" - i originally set up zfs on root before it was really supported. I had [problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246534/why-does-dkms-status-warning-diff-between-built-and-installed-module-happen) when they introduced official support in the kernel, but I really hope that is no longer having any impact. I thought I had switched to the official versions

Comment: I am running 20.04, although not zfs, and just did an `apt policy zfs-dracut` to get the version # from it. packages.ubuntu.com can also be helpful. I couldn't find 0.8.4-1 anywhere, but EOL releases aren't shown on packages.ubuntu.com I really wonder where that version of the package came from.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is because you're using `apt upgrade` and not `apt dist-upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade`. `upgrade` won't install packages if there is a requirement to install an additional package as well to fulfil the dependencies. While `dist-upgrade` and `full-upgrade` will do that.

`zfs-dracut` requires `dracut` and `zfsutils-linux` (which incidentally may have been mentioned in your "# [more irrelevant stuff here]" section you stripped).

So either `sudo apt install zfs-dracut dracut zfsutils-linux` or `sudo apt dist-upgrade` will likely get you out of this.

Comment: Pretty much hitting the nail on the head here. Also, as I understand it, `dist-upgrade` is the historical "Debian" name, while `full-upgrade` is the command name that makes sense on Ubuntu - these commands should do exactly the same - doing a *full upgrade*, including new dependencies.

Comment: The `#more irrelevant stuff here` was just that it is upgrading some other packages this time. Last time I ran it, there were none of them, hence irrelevant to the question. The packages `dracut-core` and `zfsutils-linux` both show up in `apt list --installed`, so I am thinking they are installed. Pretty sure I've tried the `full-upgrade` before, and it did not help, but I can try again.

Comment: Huh, wait you said it depends on `dracut`, which is not installed. That could indeed be the issue then... how could I have figured that out on my own, that it depends on that? (Edit: the requirements show up in `apt-cache show zfs-dracut`, i guess that's how.

Comment: When you have upgrade distributions, always do `full-upgrade` because dependencies can have changed.

Comment: Well, I did do the full upgrade right *before* the release upgrade (and afaik the `do-release-upgrade` command also does it). Pretty sure I also did it again when the message of kept back packages was there, but i can't confidently say that i did.

Comment: I went to https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/zfs-dracut to figure out the dependencies. But yeah, you can use the command-line too.

Comment: I ran `apt full-upgrade` once more and it did not even try afaict (snippet edited into the question). So I am trying the explicit `apt install` now, and that failed because it tries to access `/lib/modules/4.15.0.101-generic`, which does not exist. Could it be that apt was saying it was held back because it tried and failed to install it?

Comment: **Warning** to future readers: This can break initramfs' zfs support, and hence can break booting. It did in my case, because while `apt full-upgrade` did nothing, `apt install zfs-dracut dracut zfsutils-linux` uninstalled `zfs-initramfs`, issued a warning, then failed installing `zfs-dracut`. I fixed this up from a live stick but this is not a great outcome anyway.